# Can postfix queue message till milter comes back?

Tags: postfix, milter

I am using postfix and a before queue milter (written in java, running as a seperate process).  When milter crashes or not available for a brief period, can postfix be configured to queue till milter comes back online?  The email client should get a successful 250 Queued for delivery but postfix buffers the message till milter is available.

Comment: Best practice is for the mail server to temporarily reject the message. The sender will then try again, usually in a few minutes.

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to send temporary rejects which is the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes if you have a Postfix 2.6, else you can only accept or temporaly reject the mail if the milter is down. If it is accepted, you will not go to the milter after the mail is putting in queue.

See the milter_default_action option http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#milter_default_action

If you have postfix 2.6, the quarantine option is maybe interesting, the mail is put in hold and you will need to restart the delivery process. I don't know if it will go on the milter when you will do that action.